# How to add styled components as properties of an object literal while using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm migrating my `React` app that I've built with `styled-components` to Typescript.

In my UI components, I usually create an empty object `LS = {};` and add the `styled` components as properties of that object.

**Note:** `LS` stands for "Local styles", and I think it's a nice way to visually separate components that are declared inside the file, from components that are being imported from another module.

For example:

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PostCard from "@components/PostCard";

const LS = {};

LS.Title_DIV = styled.div`
  // SOME CSS RULES
`;

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return(
    <PostCard>
      <LS.Title_DIV>
        This is the title
      </LS.Title_DIV>
    </PostCard>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

While this worked fine in my JS environment, I'm getting errors in my TS environment.

[image]

[image]

I've tried to include this:

```
import styled, { StyledComponent } from "styled-components";

interface LS_Object { 
  [key: string]: StyledComponent
};

const LS: LS_Object = {}
```

Then the `Title_DIV` error goes away, but I get this new error:

[image]

This is my **tsconfig.json** at this point:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    // "module": "ES6",
    // "moduleResolution": "Node",
    // "noEmit": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES5",

    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  // "exclude": [
  //   "node_modules",
  //   "dist",
  //   "public"
  // ]
}
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a way that I can make this pattern work?

Comment: Seems like you have to be more specific than StyledComponent. Check this issue https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/630#issuecomment-315475109. You can try adding "StyledFunction<YourProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>>" instead of just "StyledComponent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best approach here would be something like this:

```
const LS = {
  Title_DIV: styled.div`
     //CSS
  `,
};

const MyComponent = (props) => {
      return(
        <PostCard>
          <LS.Title_DIV>
            This is the title
          </LS.Title_DIV>
        </PostCard>
      );
    };
```

If you want to explicit define the type and use interface, you can get it hovering the tag, like:
[image]

And then, use it like this:

```
import styled, { StyledComponentBase } from "styled-components";

interface LS_Object {
  Title_DIV: StyledComponentBase<"div", any, {}, never>;
}

const LS: LS_Object = {
  Title_DIV: styled.div`
    // SOME CSS RULES
  `,
};

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return(
    <PostCard>
      <LS.Title_DIV>
        This is the title
      </LS.Title_DIV>
    </PostCard>
  );
};
```

Hope it helps you, cheers!

Comment: Thanks. This could work. I also found this, so I make it more generic, without naming every property beforehand. `interface LS_Object { [key: string]: StyledComponent<any,any> }`